# How can I control if post updated

Tags: plugin-development, cache

I am trying to write cache plugin for my web site. How can I control if post or page updated or added new page or post

Answer (score 1):

add below action in your main function file of your plugin

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_project_updated_post', 10, 3 );

function my_project_updated_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  // your code goes here
  // Every time you will get updated or newly created post id here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a post or page is updated or created there is action hook triggered `save_post`. You can call your function when it happens:

```
add_action( 'save_post', function( $post_or_page_id ) {
    // Trigger your cache function or update options etc.
}, 10, 1 );
```